# Redirect to server_name from which the request came

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to redirect to the domain from which the request originated within one block?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.domain.io your.domain.io;

  return 301 https://{my.domain.io OR your.domain.io}$request_uri;
}
```

I know I can create 2 blocks - one referencing `my.domain.io` and the other `your.domain.io`. My issue is that I have quite a lot of subdomains and don't to repeat the blocks, again and again, introducing lots DRY code.

Is it done using `$host`? I am gonna try... but if it's not that let me know. ;)

**UPDATE**

Nope, `$host` is not working...

Comment: I just checked with a sample config and $host works great for me. What is the issue for you?

Comment: Thank for testing it Tarun. I realized that I dind't update pull the code from git. Without you I would think that `$host` is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Tarun Lalwani who tested my solution I realized that I didn't have up-to-date code base. So lame from me!

The solution is indeed the `$host`:

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```